# Proving that an equilateral triangle in the plane cannot have vertices on integer lattice points

Tags: recreational-mathematics, triangles

I am hoping a few of you mathematicians more experienced with writing proofs might give me some guidance here and possibly give me some ideas about how to restructure the following into a more rigorous statement.

- Prove that there does not exist an equilateral triangle in the plane whose vertices are at integer lattice points (x,y).

My response follows:

Working with an equilateral triangle symmetrical about the y-axix, Let the height of the triangle along the y-axis be B, let the base of the triangle be A and let the two remaining sides both be C.

Notice this forms two triangles where, in each triangle, C=2A. This allows us to rearrange Pythagorus' theorem such that b=Sqrt(c^2 - (2c)^2) which, after a bit of hand waving, becomes B=(sqrt(3)*sqrt(c^2))/2.

Since B cannot equal any integer value for any value of C, B cannot reside on a integer lattice point in the plane. Thus, there exists no equilateral triangle in the plane with vertices at integer lattice points (x,y).

This is day two of class.  We've yet to have any formal training in proof writing. I really do welcome and appreciate any and all advice!

Comment: Your proof is immediately flawed because you assume that the vertices of the triangle are of the form $$(x-A/2,y), (x+A/2,y), (x,y+B),$$ for suitable integers $x, y, A, B$, but this is not the most general possible form for three integer lattice points in the plane.  In particular, it is not required that one side of the triangle must be parallel to a coordinate axis, which is a restriction implied by your choice of vertices.

Comment: Ah. That seems so obvious...now. If we, just for hypothetical purposes, were allowed to add that constraint, would this logic have been correct? Also, any suggestions on how I might rethink this?

Comment: The approach that most immediately jumps out at me: First, you can assume without loss of generality that one of the vertices is at the origin. Pick some other point with integer coordinates, and then show that the only possible locations of a third vertex for an equilateral triangle are irrational. (Obviously, that requires some details to be filled in.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Assume there is a equilateral triangle whose vertices are all lattice points. Then, look at the area of the triangle using the formula $A = \dfrac{s^2\sqrt{3}}{4}$, where $s$ is the side length. Also, look at the area of the triangle using [Pick's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick's_theorem). Do you see a contradiction?

Comment: Nice. +1.  Pick's theorem is not required to see that the area of any triangle with vertices on the integer grid must have an area in $\tfrac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks. The other way I know is to use the [Shoelace Theorem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Shoelace_Theorem). Is there a better way to show that fact?

Comment: I am finishing a bit of Dif. Eq. work and then I will spend some time reading your links and attacking this problem. I will update with a new answer once I finish.  Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

There's a very nice [picture proof](https://mathoverflow.net/a/25305/30210) on Mathoverflow for a regular hexagon, but that should not be a problem.